CSS- MediaWiki - Align Gallery Overlay box centered in MonoBook Skin
I currently rewrite the MonoBook Skin to be a DarkMode one, but stumbled accross a problem with the gallery overlay css.
The Overlay shows a (default) semi translucent white box with text at the bottom, overlaying the Image.
That's fine.. changed the Box color, size and Text.
The current code is this:
ul.mw-gallery-packed-hover li.gallerybox:hover div.gallerytextwrapper,
ul.mw-gallery-packed-overlay li.gallerybox div.gallerytextwrapper,
ul.mw-gallery-packed-hover li.gallerybox.mw-gallery-focused div.gallerytextwrapper {
    position: absolute;
    background: #fff;
    background: rgba( 128, 128, 128, 0.6 );
    padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 20%;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 2px;

    p {
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 14px;
        
    }

    &:hover {
        overflow: visible;
        height: auto;
        width: 100%;
        max-height: 20%;
        max-width: 100%;

        p {
            text-overflow: clip;
            white-space: normal;
            overflow: visible;
            text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #fff, 1px -1px 0 #fff, -1px 1px 0 #fff, 1px 1px 0 #fff;
            font-size: 14px;
        }
    }
}

This now looks like this:
Overlayed Box not aligned centered
The Overlay Box is not aligned centered over the full width of the Image Box. It is aligned left, with a gap to the right..
tried to add align: center;, too. Didn't help..
Does one have experience with this and can give me a hint here?
The Overlay Box to be centered inside the Image Box.

Found a solution.
div.gallerytextwrapper {
    width: auto !important;
}

Before the code in the OP, works.
